# "SCRIPT5002 function expected" error in IE

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, iframe

i am facing an issue and getting error like 
"SCRIPT5002 function expected" in internet explorer 7-9.
this is my code :

```
 var myDiv = document.getElementById("divId"); //this line gives me "SCRIPT5002 function expected" error.

 myDiv.style.cssText("position:absolute;z-index:999");
myDiv.appendChild(
        JavaScriptCode);
```

so how to solve this??

Comment: what are you trying to accomplish? especially with the "appendChild" part? - I don't think the error is in the first line.

Comment: How is that script embedded in your page? Is it the only script?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The problem should be in the 2nd line:

```
myDiv.style.cssText("position:absolute;z-index:999");
```

[`cssText` is not a function, but a property.](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ie/ms533698%28v=vs.85%29.aspx) So call it like this:

```
myDiv.style.cssText = "position:absolute;z-index:999";
```

or (better approach in my opinion, because it is clearer):

```
myDiv.style.position = 'absolute';
myDiv.style.zIndex = 999;
```

Comment: true, but I don't think this throws a "function *expected* error".

Comment: @Bergi It does. Have a look at [this fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/n5c4Q/) using IE with the console open.

Answer (score 0):

I also got this in an attempt to check if a variable was an Element.

```
"notAnElement" instanceof Element
```

And it always throws the `function expected` error.

```
document.createElement("div") instanceof Element
```

Successfully evaluates to `true`

I haven't implemented it yet, but my solution is to use a try/catch block.